# How to call external program from vim with visual marked text as param?

Tags: vim

Call pattern: `path-to-programm visual-marked-text filetype directory`

Example: `"C:\Programme\WinGrep\grep32.exe" search-pattern *.sql D:\MyProject\build`

Comment: Do you need to replace the selected text with the output of the program?

Comment: No, I would not replace the selected text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following Vim-script function can be used to do that.

```
function! FeedVisualCmd(cmdpat)
    let [qr, qt] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
    silent norm! gvy
    let cmd = printf(a:cmdpat, shellescape(@"))
    call setreg('"', qr, qt)
    echo system(cmd)
    if v:shell_error
        echohl ErrorMsg | echom 'Failed to run ' . cmd | echohl NONE
    endif
endfunction
```

It copies currently selected text to the unnamed register (see `:help ""`),
runs given template of the command through the `printf` function, and then
executes resulting command echoing its output.

If the only part of the command that changes is pattern, it is convenient to
define a mapping,

```
vnoremap <leader>g :<c-u>call FeedVisualCmd('"C:\Programme\WinGrep\grep32.exe" %s *.sql D:\MyProject\build')<cr>
```

Answer (score 5):

You select the text and then type:

```
:!<program>
```

For instance, to sort the lines, select them and type:

```
:!sort
```

Note that this will **replace** the marked text with the output of the external program

Comment: I know this comand, but i am calling the external program with multiple arguments as you can see in the example.

Answer (score 4):

You can yank the selected text with <kbd>y</kbd> and paste it in the command line:

: ! cmd <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>  [other params]

Answer (score 0):

To pass the the highlighted text as parameter you can use xargs on linux/unix (or cygwin on windows) like this:

```
:'<,'>!xargs -I {} path-to-program {} filetype directory
```

You enter this command by highlighting text in visual mode and then typing
`:`, `!` and typing rest of command.

`{}` part of command will be replaced by the input to the xargs command which is the highlighted text. So `path-to-program` will be executed with required parameters in proper order (selected text first).

Comment: I need the visual marked text as the first argument, not as last argument.

Comment: Can I solve the problem with a Vim function? Without having to install Cygwin.